# C# How to return list of DapperRow to List of strongly types objects?

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

I have a generic method that takes in any class or a list of any class and will return a list of rows or a single row from the database.

The problem I am having is turning the list of dapper rows into a list of strongly typed objects. Can someone help here?

This is the dapper method

```
 public async Task<dynamic> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(string sqlStatement)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                var retVal = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sqlStatement);
                return retVal;
            }
        }
```

I can call this method either like this passing a list of models as I want to return this back to me.

```
var sqlStatement = $@"Select * from ClientReferral";
            var retVal= await _dapperHelper.ExecuteQueryAsync<List<ReferralModel>>(sqlStatement);
            return retVal.ToList(); <---- Errors here
```

or like this as a single query

```
      var sqlStatement = $@"Select * from ClientReferral where id = 1";
        var retVal= await _dapperHelper.ExecuteQueryAsync<ReferralModel>(sqlStatement);
```

In any case I need to convert the list of DapperRows into a list of my model

```
var retVal = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sqlStatement);

public class ReferralModel
    {
        public string? ClientName { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string? ClientNumber { get; set; }
        public string? ClientDOB { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateSubmitted { get; set; } = default;
        public string? ReportStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: and what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should change you code from `dynamic` to `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>` then it will work

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(string sqlStatement)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        var retVal = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sqlStatement);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```